# How to write (and test) a Rails class that isn't a controller or a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing a Rails app that will focus heavily on searching. For this purpose, I feel like I should split the actual `search` action on the controller off from another method to prepare the search parameters, just to make sure I can test accurately. However, I'm not sure where to put such a method. [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664618/rspec-testing-a-controller-search-method) have told me to put it into a new class, but I'm not sure where you put an extra class file in a Rails project. Is there a customary directory location people usually store extra classes? If not, how would such a method work/be tested as a private method in the same controller by which it is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually put extra classes in the lib folder. As for testing, nothing particular really. If you are using RSpec, simply do:

```
describe ExtraClass do    
  it 'saves the day'    
end
```

Comment: How would one go about loading this new class into the controller? I'm getting errors such as `uninitialized constant FirstController::NewClass`. I'm trying to use `load` in the first line of the controller file, but I'm not sure if that's how I should go about it.

Comment: Have you restarted your server first? Depending on your version of Rails, you should automatically load that class.

Comment: I'm trying to build from the ground up using TDD, so the only thing I've been restarting is my Guard/Spork test server. I named the new class SearchFilter, in the file `#{Rails.root}/lib/search_filter.rb`. Does that sound correct?

Comment: Something about the way I named the class wasn't matching Rails' constants, so I threw a `require` statement at the top of the controller and the specs passed. Thanks for your help!